# Intellij web application on tomcat server shows http://localhost:8080/index.jsp instead of http://localhost:8080/myapp/index.jsp

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, intellij-idea

I'm following a tutorial on udemy. In the tutorial he is using eclipse. But i'm following the course with intellij. Every thing works fine but one thing i keep noticing is that when he runs the servlets or jsp pages it is always shows the project name before the servlet(http://localhost:8080/myapp/index.jsp). 
But when i create an web application on intellij it just shows  http://localhost:8080/index.jsp.

So the question is how can get the project name before the /index.jsp.

I tried to add this to the web.xml file but it  does not seems to work

```
<display-name>myApp</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: It's an application context path. Set it in settings for your servlet container (e.g. Tomcat server).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can enter your application URL in the 'Edit Connfiguration' of your tomcat server.

- Click on Edit Configuration
- Enter you application URL in the start up page

[image]

Note:- Most probably above solution will work, if it doesn't then you might need to change the application context to '\myApp' in deployment tab.