# Apache Tomcat or Eclipse redirect to localhost:8080/ instead of localhost:8080/projectname/index.jsp

Tags: eclipse, apache, jsp, tomcat, url

I'm getting the same problem described in this question:
[Intellij web application on tomcat server shows http://localhost:8080/index.jsp instead of http://localhost:8080/myapp/index.jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30963259/intellij-web-application-on-tomcat-server-shows-http-localhost8080-index-jsp)
But in Eclipse. I cannot setup the URL to open the correct index.jsp and it's not trivial how to do it en Eclipse from that answer.

Comment: That sounds like the opposite problem. Can you clarify yours without pointing to a different question that also mixes in IntelliJ (are you also between Eclipse and IntelliJ)? What opens instead of the correct `index.jsp`?

Comment: I just fixed it, the confusing part was that instead of opening index.jsp, it showed the index.jsp's content, but in the /myapp directory directly. I simply restarted the whole project from scratch and it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was a misconfiguration I might have made in the process and I couldn't find. I solved the issue simply restarting a new project and copying my files there. The issue was gone by then.